# How to add admin panel Menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My plugin is successfully activated but I am not able to add the admin panel menu in WordPress. Please check the below code.

```
<?php 

add_action('admin_menu','hybreeder_admin_menu');

function hybreeder_admin_menu()

{

add_menu_page( 'hybreeder_service',
                'services', 
                'administration',
                 'hybreeder_slug', 
                 'hybreeder_admin_menu_setup',
                  'dashicons-admin-generic', 
                  '90' 
      );

}




function hybreeder_admin_menu_setup()

{

echo "<h1>hybreeder services</h1>";

}
```

Comment: I am creating my own plugin.I am a new in wordpress

Comment: Did you call your menu in header.php?

Comment: Mr.Helping Hands , I am talking about admin menu.                                 <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary' )); ?> this is in my header.php

Comment: There are lots of menu in admin like post,page,comments,appearance,user tools etc. I have to add my own menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am considering that you have all the necessary doc blocks (comments) on top of the page to make it a plugin. **Try changing the third option to something like manage_options.**

Comment: there is no issue, this menu will only be shown to users who have access to the options.php file (yoursite.com/wp-admin/options.php). by default only admins are allowed this functioanlity so this menu will only be shown to admins.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `administration` it should be `manage_options`.

So your code will be

```
add_menu_page( 'hybreeder_service',
        'services',
        'manage_options',
        'hybreeder_slug',
        'hybreeder_admin_menu_setup',
        'dashicons-admin-generic',
        '90'
);
```